# Git Color UI support for 256 Colors?

Tags: git, terminal, prompt, 256color

I am trying to colour my Git output using my native XTerm 256 color palette. 
Is there anyway to do this? I can't seem to get it to work.

for example in `.gitconfig`.

```
[color]
  ui = auto
[color 'branch']
  local = colour33
  remote = colour46
  current = colour27
```

Etc.
I know this formatting works when you specify the various basic color terms; cyan, magenta, yellow, and attributes; dim, bright, ul, bold, etc.
But I just can't find anything in regards to using the full color palette available to a 256color terminal, without actually changing the 8 basic color terms themselves, in the actual pallete.
There isn't anything in the documentation or manpages that I can find either.
I know different programs seem to use different syntax for specifying color, so I may just be using the wrong syntax or I am the only one who has ever wanted to do such a thing.

I am assuming `git-config` will only support those basic 8 colors with various attributes based on what the `git-config` man page is saying, so if this is not possible, is there a way to change those colors, in the terminals color palette BUT only for one program, like in this situation, Git? Maybe a perl script that exports those values only when `git-config` is referencing them, but unsets them soon as `git-config` is finished?

And no this is not too much trouble than its worth. I love my eyecandy in a terminal, and id do it myself if I could figure out a resource that explains something similar.

Comment: Note: if 256 colors are not enough, git 2.3.0 (February 2015) will allow 24-bits colors! See [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27609678/6309)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The syntax for the color is: `[fg [bg]] [attr]...`

As for the colors, you can use the **named ones** (normal, black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, and white) or **just a number** of the color in the 256 palette without any prefix.

The supported attributes are: bold, dim, ul, blink, and reverse.

So your configuration might look like this (tested with git 1.8.5.3):

```
[color "branch"]
    local = 33 
    remote = 46
    current = 27
```

I have taken a look into the [git source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4c7f1819b3c142ace98269a556bc929c80e7c9fd/color.c#L29) to find the answer.

Comment: Btw, to test the color, you can use something like `echo $(git config --get-color "" "120 bold reverse") color test $(git config --get-color "" reset)`

Answer (score 4):

Note that:

---

- the support for colors is **now documented** (January 2015, Git 2.2.2, [commit 0edad17](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0edad17d6728df055c3b92bf89d5329f0afdcefd) ) :

> #### docs: describe ANSI 256-color mode
>
> Our color specifications have supported the 256-color ANSI extension for years, but we never documented it.

[`git config` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) now includes:

> Colors (foreground and background) may also be given as numbers between 0 and 255;
>   these use [ANSI 256-color mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#cite_ref-15) (but note that not all terminals may support this)

---

- using numerical value for the color will be more robust with Git 2.2.2 (January 2015).
  See [commit d0e08d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d0e08d62335ce9685ac547287771e589587334b6) from [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff):

### config: fix parsing of "`git config --get-color some.key -1`"

> Most of git-config's command line options use `OPT_BIT` to choose an action, and then parse the non-option arguments in a context-dependent way. However, `--get-color` and `--get-colorbool` are unlike the rest of the options, in that they are `OPT_STRING`, taking the option name as a parameter.
>
> This generally works, because we then use the presence of those strings to set an action bit anyway. But it does mean that the option-parser will continue looking for options even after the key (because it is not a non-option; it is an argument to an option). And running:

```
git config --get-color some.key -1
```

> (to use "`-1`" as the default color spec) will barf, claiming that "`-1`" is not an option.
>   Instead, we should treat `--get-color` and `--get-colorbool` as action bits, just like `--add`, `--get`, and all the other actions, and then check that the non-option arguments we got are sane.
>   This fixes the weirdness above, and makes those two options like all the others.
>
> **[This "fixes" a test in `t/t4026-color.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb357221a402c55b23bf99ec9f3b361709d45fa7), which checked that feeding "`-2`" as a color should fail** (it does fail, but prior to this patch, because `parseopt` barfed, not because we actually ever tried to parse the color).
>
> **This also catches other errors**, like:

```
git config --get-color some.key black blue
```

> **which previously silently ignored "`blue`"** (and now will complain that you gave too many arguments).
>
> **There are some possible regressions, though.
>
>   We now disallow these, which currently do what you would expect**:

```
  # specifying other options after the action
  git config --get-color some.key --file whatever

  # using long-arg syntax
  git config --get-color=some.key
```

---

If 256 colors are not enough, you can import even more colors.
See [commit 17a4be2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17a4be26060b00a867cbe54ee906fe03813470ec) (Git 2.3.0, Q1 2015)

> #### `parse_color`: support 24-bit RGB values
>
> Some terminals (like XTerm) allow full 24-bit RGB color specifications using an extension to the regular ANSI color scheme.
>   Let's allow users to specify hex RGB colors, **enabling the all-important feature of hot pink ref decorations**:

```
git log --format="%h%C(#ff69b4)%d%C(reset) %s"
```